# Show only the difference column when using add_difference function in gt_summary

Tags: r, gtsummary

When creating a table with the add_difference function like this

```
  trial %>%
  select(trt, age, marker, response, death) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = trt,
    missing = "no"
  ) %>%
  add_difference()
```

You get a table with the difference column and p_value and CI columns. [image]

I want to remove those columns as I want to add p_values for a nonparametric test for continuous variables, which to my understanding from [this documentation](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/gtsummary/html/tests.html), can't be done using add_difference.

If I use modify_column_hide(columns = c(p.value, ci))
and than add_p i'll get an error:

```
trial %>%
  select(trt, age, marker, response, death) %>% tbl_summary(
    by = trt,
    missing = "no" ) %>%
  add_difference() %>% 
  modify_column_hide(columns = c(p.value, ci)) %>% 
  add_p()

#Error: `add_p()` cannot be run after `add_difference()` or `add_p()` when a #'p.value' column is already present.
```

What is the correct approach to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how i would do it...

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.7.0'

trial %>%
  select(trt, age, marker, response, death) %>% tbl_summary(
    by = trt,
    missing = "no" ) %>%
  add_difference() %>% 
  modify_column_hide(columns = c(p.value, ci)) %>% # hide the CI and p-value
  modify_table_body(~.x %>% select(-p.value)) %>% # remove the p-value from the table 
  modify_footnote(estimate = NA) %>% # remove difference footnote
  add_p() %>% # add new p-values
  as_kable() # convert to kable so it will display on stackoverflow
```

| **Characteristic** | **Drug A**, N = 98 | **Drug B**, N = 102 | **Difference** | **p-value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Age | 46 (37, 59) | 48 (39, 56) | -0.44 | 0.7 |
| Marker Level (ng/mL) | 0.84 (0.24, 1.57) | 0.52 (0.19, 1.20) | 0.20 | 0.085 |
| Tumor Response | 28 (29%) | 33 (34%) | -4.2% | 0.5 |
| Patient Died | 52 (53%) | 60 (59%) | -5.8% | 0.4 |

<sup>Created on 2023-01-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. The problem with your suggestion is that, to my understanding, I still can't use add_p afterward. I added a clarification to the original question.

Comment: Post is now updated

Comment: Awesome so the key is the modify_table_body.
Thank you!